# How to get an Objective-C property's declared attributes at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Assuming an Objective-C Property declared as follow: `@property (nonatomic, strong) id foobar;`

The Objective-C runtime provides `objc_property_attribute_t` which should contain/encode the value of each property's declared attribute (`nonatomic`, etc ...)

However, I could not find in the Objective-C runtime documentation an API to access the property's attributes, namely in my example: `nonatomic and strong` and objc_property_t is an opaque type.

Hence my question, **how to get an Objective-C property's declared attributes at runtime ?**

Comment: Is that what you are looking for: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101-SW6 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Larme's link, the API to get an Objective-C property attributes at runtime is `property_getAttributes` defined in `<objc/runtime.h>`